# What is the relation between the Gribov problem and color confinement?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, yang-mills, confinement

I have heard that the [Gribov problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gribov_ambiguity) is in some way related to [color confinement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_confinement) (For instance: [Gribov copies and confinement](https://arxiv.org/abs/0709.1671)). Although I understand what both the Gribov and confinement problems are, I do not see any relation between them and the few papers I have found are quite too technical and remain unclear to me.

Is there a simple intuitive explanation of how the Gribov problem solution may explain confinement in QCD? An introductory reference would be great as well.

Comment: In my (humble) opinion there is no connection at all.  The lattice approach to gauge theories gives us confinement, and there is no need for gauge fixing on the lattice. The Gribov game started before before confinement was understood and presumably came from the idea that "gauge fixing ambiguities  and confinement are both  difficult problems, so they must be related."

Comment: @mikestone I found this well cited review [The Gribov problem and QCD dynamics](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.1491) which clearly suggests a relation between confinement and the Gribov problem (check the abstract for instance). I am struggling to fully understand it though.

Comment: Thanks -- It looks like a sound article. It makes clear that the issue is not the ambiguity of the gauge fixing (which is the way I have always seen Gribov  described before) but  in fact provides a tool for analysing the global topology of the configuration space.  Thanks again for the ref!

Comment: @Diracology From the paper you mentioned, it doesn't seem like the Gribov problem and confinement are directly related. The relation is between BRST symmetry and confinement, which is logical because the BRST operator is what defines a state as appearing in the spectrum (physical states are BRST closed but not exact). The Gribov problem arises from choosing certain "gauge-fixing" (BRST exact) terms to add to your Lagrangian, which is done to yield finite results for perturbative calculations. So in a way, BRST symmetry and hence confinement are on a higher plane than the Gribov problem...